# N Gram Script error: ReferenceError: "ScriptyApp" is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, ads

Ive been trying to run Ngram Script to analyse Neg Kws from Google Ads, and i've been getting this error:
ReferenceError: "ScriptyApp" is not defined.

Can anyone help me get the solution? Thank You!

Comment: Hi Tomas. welcome to SO. Can you provide your code as well? you can check the best practices in asking questions here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) indeed, as the tag suggests, then this is likely just a typo in your code. It should be `ScriptApp`, not Script**y**App.

Comment: Hi Enrique,
Thank you for your answer. I understand that, but when i look up for "ScriptyApp" i cant find it in the code, thats what i dont get it.
I would like to post the complete code but its too long

Comment: Can you share the code you're using then? Please please follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) posted in a comment to your question and try to provide all necessary information in your question, to help you get more accurate answers with less back 'n forth.

Comment: I have the same issue. It is very hard to find anything pertaining to it.